# Puppet master certificate generation Not working

Tags: ssl, puppet

***Puppet Master:***

- Docker container with cent-OS-6
- configured in /etc/hosts
- configured /etc/puppet/puppet.conf with **server**,**dns_alt_names** and
  **certname**

**Puppet Agent:**

- Docker container  with ubuntu OS
- configured serverip and agent ip in /etc/hosts
- configure /etc/puppet/puppet.conf with **server** value

**NOW trying to Generate Certificate in SERVER Machine with**

```
sudo -u puppet puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose
```

Displays:*`Notice: Starting Puppet master version 3.8.7`*

*Nothing happens  related to Certificate Generation.*

I believe there aint any mistake in hosts file and other configuration missing. here might have things gone wrong.

**In the client machine**
If I run this command **puppet agent -t** . I get the following error. As the certificate is not generated in server. I think I have to fix that first than this .

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://www.puppetmaster.com/pluginfacts: Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://www.puppetmaster.com/plugins: Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
```

Comment: That looks like a malformed `puppet.conf`. Could you post the client Puppet config file?

Comment: The agent seems to be configured to look to a machine named "www.puppetmaster.com" as the master, but although it can reach the puppet service on that machine, that name is not one of those recorded on the master's cert.  Probably that means that the master thinks its name is different.

Comment: As for the master not generating a certificate, if indeed it does not do so then the most likely reason would be that it already has one.  Perhaps you included one in the Docker container, and that could be a problem.